# Instantiate classes used in Flask routes at runtime

Tags: python, flask, global-variables

It seems to be pretty common practice to have global scope class instances that are used in flask routes, something like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class Utility:
    def get_properties():
       pass

util_obj = Utility()

@app.route('/aaa/bbb/ccc',methods=['POST'])
def func1():
  util_obj.get_properties()
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

But what if the Utility class has attributes that need to be instantiated at runtime?

```
import argparse
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class Utility:
    def __init__(self, x): # x is only known at runtime
        self.x = x
    def get_properties(self):
       pass

util_obj = Utility() # This will fail, as we need "x"

@app.route('/aaa/bbb/ccc',methods=['POST'])
def func1():
  util_obj.get_properties()
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("x") # This needs to be used to instantiate the Utility class
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

How can this be done cleanly?

I have tried to create a function that creates the app and instantiates the class, but that feels like bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are likely after is the application context

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/

Or sessions

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#sessions

Both of these are useful for storing data and/or returning objects at runtime. The application context in particular is used in the Flask documentation to initialise databases and return their cursor/handle at runtime. I would follow the Flask documentation quickstart and tutorials for a thorough explanation of how to setup a project this way.

Using what you have there though, you could just set self.x to a default value and change it before initialising your application.

```py
import argparse
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class Utility:
    def __init__(self): # x is only known at runtime
        self.x = None
    def get_properties(self):
       pass

util_obj = Utility() # This will fail, as we need "x"

@app.route('/aaa/bbb/ccc',methods=['POST'])
def func1():
  util_obj.get_properties()
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("x") # This needs to be used to instantiate the Utility class
    args = parser.parse_args()
    util_obj.x = args.x
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```